# Ensure trained word embeddings get high similarity with particular words

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word-embeddings

I am trying out my hand at training a Word2Vec model using gensim. I made a simple training file that basically had just one line repeated multiple times

```
entertainment films Movies cinema
entertainment Movies 
entertainment films
entertainment cinema
```

The idea behind using a training file like the one above is to ensure that words like movies, etc come out to be most similar to entertainment.

```
>>> wv_model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sents, size=300, min_count=1, 
    workers=8, window=1, sg=0)
```

But when I check the results I entertainment actually has a negative similarity score

```
>>> wv_model.most_similar(positive=['Movies'])
[('cinema', 0.14602532982826233), ('films', -0.022810805588960648), ('entertainment', -0.030070479959249496)]
```

The result I am trying to achieve is to ensure that the most similar word for `movies`, `films`, `cinema` comes out to be `entertainment`

Answer (score 0):

*Word2vec* (or, e.g. *GloVe*) learn similar embeddings for words that occur in *similar contexts (i.e. co-occur with the same distribution of words) not words co-occurring directly.$^*$ This makes sense intuitively since words that appear together aren't necessarily *similar* (e.g. synonymous), but may be otherwise *related*, e.g. *blue* and *sky*.

e.g. say *film* and *movie* each co-occur a lot with words like *actor*, *director*, *rating*, etc then their embeddings will be similar (relative to those of other words) - even if *movie* and *film* are never seen together (which is often the case for synonyms as you would say one or the other).

[$^*$ of course, if two words frequently appear together then their contexts may well be similar.]

To deliberately force embeddings of two words $w_1, w_2$ to be similar is not trivial (unless you manually change their embeddings..) since the embeddings capture statistics from the corpus. For word2vec to learn similar embeddings, the distributions of words that co-occur with $w_1, w_2$ must be similar. One way(/hack) to do that could be to duplicate the corpus and in the second copy replace all instances of $w_1$ with $w_2$ and vice versa. Then train on both copies joined together.

[**More detail if interested**: Words that do directly co-occur typically have a higher *dot product* between their embeddings since that approximates their associated *pointwise mutual information* (e.g. see [this paper](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5477-neuralword-embedding-as-implicit-matrix-factorization.pdf) for info). However, *similarity* is estimated by the cosine of the angle between embeddings (1 if identical, 0 if orthogonal, etc), which checks if embeddings are in the same direction. Since the embedding of a word reflects the distribution of all words that co-occur with it (e.g. see [this paper](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/8965-what-the-vec-towards-probabilistically-grounded-embeddings.pdf)), embeddings having similar directions tends to indicate words that have similar co-occurrence distributions, i.e. *similarity*.]